# Spring Scala with Play2: object springframework is not a member of package org

Tags: spring, scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

I'm new in scala and I'm trying to use Spring Scala as di framework in simple helloWorld scala-play application. According to this article I placed Global object into root of application.
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaDependencyInjection

Here is my Global object:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext

object Global extends play.api.GlobalSettings {

  private val context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext()

  override def getControllerInstance[A](controllerClass: Class[A]): A = {
    context.getBean(controllerClass)
  }
}
```

And sbt file:

```
name := """test"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

resolvers += "SpringSource Milestone Repository" at "http://repo.springsource.org/milestone"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  ws,
  "org.springframework.scala" % "spring-scala" % "1.0.0.M1"
)
```

And with all this stuff I get an Exception:

```
play.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[object springframework is not a member of package org]
    at play.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27) ~[na:na]
    at play.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:27) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
```

As I understand after googling it could be because of default package and relative imports, but it didn't help me very much because suggested solutions, like `_root_` before spring package, didn't work. Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect the dependency failed download. What you've got looks ok but I wouldn't use spring-scala. It looks like a dead project to me. No release since 2013.

Comment: I've tried Scala Spring in simple sbt app, without Play and it worked, so I suppose downloading should not be a problem, because except Play everything was the same. And thank you for pointing out that project haven't had releases since 2013, I didn't pay attention to this. I'll look for other DI frameworks for Scala.